# Как пользоваться регулярными выражениями в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, регулярные-выражения

Есть таблица:

```
+----+------+                                     
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Stas |
|  2 | Ann  |
|  3 | Jack |
|  4 | Jack |
+----+------+
```

Пытаюсь вытащить записи, где `name` начинаются на `[AS]`:

```
SELECT * FROM first WHERE name LIKE '[AS]%'
```

Но, в ответ только:

> Empty set (0.00 sec)

Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синтаксис `LIKE "[AS]%"` предполагает что под это условие попадут поля вида
`[AS]1` `[AS]S` и т. д. Таким образом ни `Ann`, ни `Stas` под это условие не попадут.

Использование `LIKE "AS%"`также не выдаст ни ни `Ann`, ни `Stas`, так как опять же данные строки не начинаются с `AS`.

Если требуется найти имена начинающиеся с `A` или `S` надо использовать `REGEXP`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM first WHERE name REGEXP '^(A|S)';
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp  -  в этом источнике все работает (Скрольте вниз)

Comment: Сайт w3schools часто называют w3fools. Проблема указанного вами мануала в том, что поддержка квадратных скобок в `LIKE` в MySQL отсутствует,  а в MSSQL - присутствует.  Но в мануале эта особенность **не отмечается**.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, в операторе `LIKE` ни расширенными, ни регулярными выражениями и не пахнет.
Урезанный функционал регулярных выражений можно получить в операторе `REGEXP`

Судя по ответам, синтаксис регулярных выражений оказался очень сложен.

Изначально автор хотел вот так

```
SELECT * FROM first WHERE name REGEXP '^[as]';
```

Answer (score -1):

Если используешь `LIKE`, то квадратные скобки не обрабатываются, идет просто сравнение по тексту (и %). А раз записей вида `[AS]..` нет, то и результат пустой.

Для регулярных выражений используй [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)